# Chrome sporadically asks me to install GWT Developer Plugin incorrectly

Tags: google-chrome, gwt

Chrome sporadically gives me the following message incorrectly:

- Development Mode requires the Google Web Toolkit Developer Plugin By
  downloading, you agree to the Terms & Conditions and Privacy Policy.
  Download the GWT Developer Plugin

I already have the plugin installed. Would someone please give me pointers to troubleshoot this issue?

Below are some info about my development environment:
Chrome: 21.0.1180.89 m
Eclipse
Version: Juno Release
Build id: 20120614-1722

Thanks in advance for your help.

-Otosaat

Comment: Does that help? http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/TroubleshootingOOPHM

Comment: Hi Thomas, thank you for the link. I'll go thru it. In the mean time, I was able to get it working by restarting the Chrome browser.

Answer (score 1):

do not use the direct link to add gwt plugin . go to settings and then in extention option there find the gwt plugin and add it  . . may be this will help you.